# Encrypt Stored Procedure in Sql Server 2016

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, model-view-controller

I have stored procedure in my database and don't want to share that logic with others so is there any way to encrypt my stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Try it's

```
create procedure sp_encrypt
with encryption
as
begin
select 1
end
```

Comment: Ensure that if you lose the code it will be difficult to recover it

Comment: Also worth noting that `with encryption` should really called be  `with obsfucation` as its not particularly secure to others with server access.